# Three problems with my JavaScript number sorter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 problems that I can see so far with my number sorting function in JavaScript.

1. One of the numbers in my array is showing as null. Not sure why this is, because it only happens once the rest of the time that very same number shows fine.
2. I am splicing all the lowest numbers from one array and pushing them into another, which leaves with me with the biggest number in the array left and I am not sure how to get that pushed into the new array. I have tried

`if(array.length <= 1){newArray.push(array[0]);`

3. If I try to sort any other array than my "numbers" array then I crash the browser and get a NS_ERROR_FAILURE. So if I try to sort "numbersTwo" for example.

Here is my code:

```js
let numbers = [5, 123, 12, 11, 668, 4345, 7688, 65, 333, 221, 545, 7788, 908];

let numbersTwo = [5, 4, 75, 53, 22, 3, 765, 1, 5, 10];

let sortedNumbers = [];

console.log(numbers);

function remove(arrayToSplice, item) {
  let array = arrayToSplice;
  let index = array.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function sortNumbers(array, newArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let numberToCompare = array[i];
    document.writeln("<br> I " + array[i] + " <br>");

    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      document.writeln("J " + array[j] + ", ");

      if (array[j] < numberToCompare) {
        numberToCompare = array[j];
        document.write("<br> The comparison number is now " + numberToCompare + "<br>");
        i--;
      }
    }

    if (!newArray.includes(numberToCompare)) {
      document.write("<br>" + numberToCompare + " gets pushed <br>");
      newArray.push(numberToCompare);
      // After I have pushed this, I want to remove it.
      remove(array, numberToCompare);
    }
  }
}

sortNumbers(numbers, sortedNumbers);
console.log(numbers);
console.log(sortedNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1: The reason you're getting `undefined` is because you decrement `i` every time you change the comparison number. If you do this enough times, `i` becomes `-2`. The next time the outer loop repeats, you increment `i` to `-1`, then you do `numberToCompare = array[i];`, which returns `undefined` because there's no `-1` element in the array. You could check if you go below `-1` and skip the decrement.

I'm not really sure why you're decrementing `i` at this point, though. I think you actually should do it when you remove the element from the array, if the removed element is before `i`, because when that happens all the remaining indexes get shifted down and you need to back up to process the next element. Ideally you should return the index that was removed, check whether it's lower than `i`, and only decrement `i` in that case.

Problem 2: When you get to the last two elements, you push the smaller one onto `newArray`, then increment `i`. It reaches `array.length`, so the loop stops and you don't processes the last element. You could just push the last element at the end of the function.

Problem 3: `numbersTwo` has a duplicate element `5`. You only push a value into `newArray` and remove it from `array` if it doesn't already exist in `newArray`. So the second `5` stays in the array, and the loop never finishes. If you only want unique elements in the result, you could skip pushing the value, but still remove it. If it's OK to have duplicates in the result, you can just get rid of the `if (newArray.includes(numberToCompare))` check completely.

```js
let numbers = [5, 123, 12, 11, 668, 4345, 7688, 65, 333, 221, 545, 7788, 908];

let numbersTwo = [5, 4, 75, 53, 22, 3, 765, 1, 5, 10];

let sortedNumbers = [];

console.log(numbers);

function remove(arrayToSplice, item) {
  let array = arrayToSplice;
  let index = array.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    document.writeln("Splice out index " + index + "<br>");
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return index;
}

function sortNumbers(array, newArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let numberToCompare = array[i];
    document.writeln("<br> I " + i + " " + array[i] + " <br>");

    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      document.writeln("J " + j + " " + array[j] + ", ");

      if (array[j] < numberToCompare) {
        numberToCompare = array[j];
        document.write("<br> The comparison number is now " + numberToCompare + "<br>");
      }
    }
  }

  if (!newArray.includes(numberToCompare)) {
    document.write("<br>" + numberToCompare + " gets pushed <br>");
    newArray.push(numberToCompare);
    // After I have pushed this, I want to remove it.
  }
  let removed = remove(array, numberToCompare);
  if (removed >= 0 && removed <= i) {
    i--;
    document.writeln("Decrement I to " + i + "<br>");

  }
  // Push remaining element that's left over from loops
  if (array.length) {
    newArray.push(array[0]);
    array.splice(0, 1);
  }
}

sortNumbers(numbers, sortedNumbers);
console.log(numbers);
console.log(sortedNumbers);

sortedNumbers = [];
console.log(numbersTwo);
sortNumbers(numbersTwo, sortedNumbers);
console.log(numbersTwo);
console.log(sortedNumbers);
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should post my final code here as this is working but I haven't used the code from the answers.

I have removed the check to see if the new array already includes the current lowest number because I would like to keep duplicates in.

I have changed the time when my index gets subtracted by 1 to after the it has been removed from the array to avoid undefined errors. As Barmar suggested.

I have also added two declarations of variables in the function itself, so that the original array is not modified and so I do not have to pass a destination array.

```
let numbers = [5, 123, 12, 11, 668, 4345, 7688, 65, 333, 221, 545, 7788, 908, 45412];

let numbersTwo = [5, 4, 75, 53, 22, 3, 765, 1, 5, 10];

let sortedNumbers = [];

function remove(arrayToSplice, item) {
  let array = arrayToSplice;
  let index = array.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
   array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function sortNumbers(array) {
  let arrayCopy = array.slice();
  let resultArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayCopy.length; i++) {
    let numberToCompare = arrayCopy[i];
   document.writeln("<br> I " + array[i] + " " + array.indexOf(i) + " <br>");

    for (let j = 0; j < arrayCopy.length; j++) {
      document.writeln("J " + arrayCopy[j] + ", ");

      if (numberToCompare && arrayCopy[j] < numberToCompare) {
        numberToCompare = arrayCopy[j];
        document.write("<br> The comparison number is now " + numberToCompare +  "<br>");
      }
    }
      document.write("<br>" + numberToCompare + " gets pushed <br>");
      resultArray.push(numberToCompare);
      // After I have pushed this, I want to remove it.
      remove(arrayCopy, numberToCompare);
      i--;   
  } return resultArray;
}

console.log(sortNumbers(numbersTwo));

console.log(sortNumbers(numbers));
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer to question #1 is due to the fact that you subtract 1 from i each time you find a lower number than previous. If you track i during your entire loop, you see that for the undefined variable, i equals -1. You need to use a ternary operator to ensure i never goes below 0. Also, I should say at this point that there are comparison algos out here with much better logic than what you have made. Google search for some to see how they do things and you'll see how you are taking quite a few unnecessary steps to sort your array.

As for question #3, your second array is constructed so that it causes i to become so negative that your logic gets stuck in its own loop. Just replace "i < array.length" with "i < 1" and you will see the problem.

Comment: I don't think the stuck loop is because it's getting too negative, I think it's because of the duplicate element 5.

Comment: But your explanation was my original assumption.